# debuginfo handling within fedora, how to remove debuginfo

Tags: gdb, fedora, dnf, debug-information

I can simply install debug info's for several packages with e.g:

```
sudo dnf debuginfo-install ibus-gtk3-1.5.21-5.fc31.x86_64
```

But I did not see any command to remove the debuginfos.

Is there any dnf command which can remove debuginfos?

I know that I can manually remove any package with dnf, as long as I know the name. But I can't find out automatically the relation between the package and the debuginfo to that package for remove/uninstall.

Is there any trick to do that job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [globbing](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dnf.8.html#SPECIFYING_PACKAGES):

```
# dnf remove '*-debuginfo' '*-debugsource'
```